# Windows CNG ECDH Secret Agreement structure

Tags: windows, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman, cng

I've spent a few days by searching what structure does ECDH secret agreement have, but no success. I found in MSDN that the [NCryptSecretAgreement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function sets a pointer to an NCRYPT_SECRET_HANDLE variable that receives a handle that represents the secret agreement value. I'm not familar with WinAPI at all so I simply can't do anything but reading docs.

I need to exchange keys between a Windows-based desktop app and a web app. **What I need to know is how exactly CNG's KDF uses (hashes in my case) the secret agreement value.** I'm using the SHA-256 algorithm as KDF and trying to hash X and Y of the secret agreement but result doesn't match to the one CNG computes. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot vouch for what Microsoft found fit to implement, but there is a standard on ECDH called [X9.63](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ANSI%20X9.63:2001). In that standard, ECDH works like this:

- You run the DH thing, yielding the common curve point *(X, Y)* (that's the point you got from the peer, multiplied by your secret DH value).
- You convert *X* (and only *X*; *Y* is discarded) into a sequence of bytes which we will call *Z*. Conversion is unsigned big-endian, and uses the field size: if *X* lives in field *F<sub>q</sub>*, then the conversion yields exactly *ceil(ceil(log q)/8)*. E.g. if you use the NIST P-521 curve, you work modulo a prime *q* which is such that *2<sup>520</sup> < q < 2<sup>521</sup>*, so *ceil(log q) = 521* and the resulting byte sequence consists in exactly 66 bytes, whatever the value *X*. With the most commonly used elliptic curve (known as "P-256"), that's 32 bytes.
- To derive *Z* into a key, with a hash function *H* which has an output length of *n* bytes (e.g. *n = 32* with SHA-256), you compute the potentially infinite string *H<sub>1</sub>||H<sub>2</sub>||H<sub>3</sub>||...* where "*||*" denotes concatenation, and *H<sub>i</sub> = H(Z||i)* where "*i*" is represented as four bytes, using big-endian convention. In plain words, you hash *Z* along with a 32-bit counter, and do so again and again until you have enough bytes for your intended key length.

Comment: A big thank you for clear and useful answer. Seems CNG computes it as X9.63 defines. I change the code but now there's another smaller problem: now it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. But I hash only Z without any iteration and counters. That's wrong approach, correct? But using that, keys sometimes correspond. I'm using P256 with SHA256 so the hash output has the same size as that of key – 32. In that case in the way you described (X.9.63) key is H(Z||00||00||00||01), correct? Does iteration start from 1? Or 0? Did I miss something?

Comment: The standard says that it should be H(Z||0x00||0x00||0x00||0x01) (the counter starts at 1). If you got a "correct" key with H(Z), even only once, then this proves that CNG does not follow the standard. But something else. Possibly, CNG encodes X as a minimal-sized _signed_ sequence (i.e. first byte will have its most significant bit cleared; an extra byte of value 0x00 will be added if necessary) and hashes that; it would match H(Z) about half of the time.

Comment: Based on your answers, finally found what KDFs CNG does use. Here they are: [Microsoft Windows 7 Kernel Mode Cryptographic Primitives
Library (cng.sys) Security Policy Document](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140sp/140sp1328.pdf). But the problem still exists – I cannot match keys every time. Sometimes H(Z) works, but most of the time – doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. Finally, I fugured it out and now keys match always. You were right, CNG adds extra '0' byte. However, it works for H(Z) only and not for H(Z||counter) as X9.63 defines although the abovementioned security policy document says that CNG's KDFs supports FIPS approved SP800-56A (Section 5.8), X9.63, and X9.42 key derivation. Perhaps there's still something I missed.